# Sorting an array of object given an initial value to always be first

Tags: javascript, typescript, sorting

Given an array and variable as following..

```
array = ['complete','in_progress','planned'];
value = 'planned';
```

I want to sort the array always starting with the 'value' variable
the output should display.

```
array = ['planned','in_progress','complete'];
```

eg.

```
array = ['complete','in_progress','planned'];
value = 'in_progress';
```

output would be...

```
array = ['in_progress','complete','planned'];
```

I tried different ways but I failed to come with a decent solution. Any clean and short ideas?

Comment: In the first example, why is `"complete"` moved to the end? It is neither keeping the original relative position nor is it sorted alphabetically

Answer (score 1):

You can sort and give higher priority to `value` - if it matches one of the arguments, then it will be sorted before anything. If neither of the two items is `value`, then just sort normally.

```js
const array = ['complete','in_progress','planned'];
const value = 'in_progress';

array.sort((a, b) => {
  //a comes first
  if (a == value) return -1;
  //b comes first
  if (b == value) return 1;
  
  //neither matches `value` - compare them normally
  return a.localeCompare(b);
});

console.log(array);
```

And this is the shorter version of the same by (somewhat) abusing type coercion:

```js
const array = ['complete','in_progress','planned'];
const value = 'in_progress';

array.sort((a,b) => ((a == value) * -1) || b == value || a.localeCompare(b));

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

From the top of my head you can try

```
array = ['complete','in_progress','planned'];
target = 'in_progress';

const answer = array.filter((element) => element !== target)
    .sort()
    .reduce((accumulator, value) => [...accumulator, value], [target]);
```

edit: I forgot it needs to be sorted.

Comment: Why reduce? I don't think adding a value to the front of the array is the time and place for this method. You can use `unshift` to add to the front. If you really want to do it in one continuous operation, then why not just `[target].concat(/* filter + sort */)`? That's not that great, either but at least it's not using `reduce` for an operation that is so trivial.

Comment: Yes, concat is much better actually for this problem. First thing that came to mind was to use reduce.